# Problema: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Buenas tardes estoy desarrollando una app y he rehutilizado este codigo varias veces y siempre me ha funcionado, pero ahora me lanza el siguiente error cuando lo ejecuto:

**com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type**

Mi BD:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utilizando un recyclerview con su adapter, intento que el recyclerview recorra estos datos.

Codigo donde me genera el problema:

```
homeModelList = new ArrayList<>();

mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Listas").child(post.getLid());
Toast.makeText(ProductListActivity.this, post.getLid(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        homeModelList.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            HomeModel homeModel = snapshot.getValue(HomeModel.class); <--- me genera el problema
                if (post.getLid().equals(post.getUidL())){
                    homeModelList.add(homeModel);
                }
        }

        mAdapter = new ProductoAdapter(getApplicationContext(), homeModelList);
        recycler_viewLista.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Clase de mis objetos:

```
public class HomeModel implements Serializable {
private String Titulo;
private String Uid;
private String Lid;
private String Producto;
private Integer Cantidad;
private String UidL;

public HomeModel() {
}

public HomeModel(String titulo, String uid, String lid, String producto, Integer cantidad, String uidL) {
    Titulo = titulo;
    Uid = uid;
    Lid = lid;
    Producto = producto;
    Cantidad = cantidad;
    UidL = uidL;
}

public String getTitulo() {
    return Titulo;
}

public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    Titulo = titulo;
}

public String getUid() {
    return Uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    Uid = uid;
}

public String getLid() {
    return Lid;
}

public void setLid(String lid) {
    Lid = lid;
}

public String getProducto() {
    return Producto;
}

public void setProducto(String producto) {
    Producto = producto;
}

public Integer getCantidad() {
    return Cantidad;
}

public void setCantidad(Integer cantidad) {
    Cantidad = cantidad;
}

public String getUidL() {
    return UidL;
}

public void setUidL(String uidL) {
    UidL = uidL;
}
```

}

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, ya que no encuentro la razon del error.

Comment: en qué línea tira el error?

Comment: HomeModel homeModel = snapshot.getValue(HomeModel.class); Arriba le puse una flecha.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia el tipo de **Integer** a **int** en tu modelo `HomeModel`

```
private int Cantidad;
```

El problema esta en que el tipo de variable debe ser exactamente igual a las que pones en Firebase, tambien su nombre debe ser el mismo.

Cuando usas `Integer` te referis al objecto pero no al primitivo `int`